# How to link and use remote cplex in my C++ program

Tags: c++, ssh, cplex

I can access to remote server of my university using SSH, and i want to use the cplex which is in the server in my c++ local program.

The solver is installed in the server, so I tried to connect to the server and include the cplex file in my C++ program but the compilation doesn't work!

```
#include <cplex/bin/cplex>
```

Please how can i use a remote solver in local? and how can i compile my C++ program in this case?!

Thank you.

Comment: _"...compilation doesn't work!..."_ what exactly does not work and what errors are reported?

Comment: @RichardCritten error is as follow: `fatal error: cplex/bin/cplex: No such file or directory
 #include <cplex/bin/cplex>
compilation terminated`, and my C++ project is in the local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic involved in a `#include` statement - just about any contemporary implementation consists of reading a file from the filesystem. The paths it considers are influenced with compiler arguments.

However, your description makes it sound like the files you want are residing on a remote system. Unless you are able to mount the remote directories to appear as part of your local filesystem, you need to either copy them to your local machine, or compile it *on* the remote server.

Comment: thank you @olipro for your answer, i copied i copied just the cplex and concert folders from the server to my machine but now  i can't use it, for example, can't compile the examples. Cplex is installed on my university's server,  but I cannot install it on my machine (the executable of cplex is interactive, how can I use it ?! do I even have to copy the lisence and other files also?!!